# Assembler for Hack Assembly Language in Python

Tags: python, assembly

My Python implementation of for Hack Assembly Language.  See [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83775/assembler-for-hack-assembly-language-take-2) for the Java implementation. Any comment about best practices and performance improvement?

```
import sys
import os

def usage():
    print "Usage: %s namefile.asm" % os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])

def tobin(val, nbits):
  return bin((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits))[2:]

def main():
    #command-line argument
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if "-h" in args or "--help" in args or args==[]:
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)
    fw = open(args[0].split('.')[0]+".hack",'w')

    #init compTable
    compT = {
          '0':'0101010',  '1':'0111111', '-1':'0111010',  'D':'0001100',  'A':'0110000',
         '!D':'0001101', '!A':'0110001', '-D':'0001111', '-A':'0110011','D+1':'0011111',
        'A+1':'0110111','D-1':'0001110','D+A':'0000010','D-A':'0010011','A-D':'0000111',
        'D&A':'0000000','D|A':'0010101',  'M':'1110000', '!M':'1110001', '-M':'1110011',
        'M+1':'1110111','M-1':'1110010','D+M':'1000010','D-M':'1010011','M-D':'1000111',
        'D&M':'1000000','D|M':'1010101','A-1':'0110010'
        }
    #init destTable
    destT ={'null':'000','M':'001','D':'010','MD':'011',
            'A':'100','AM':'101','AD':'110','AMD':'111'}

    #init jumpTable
    jumpT ={'null':'000','JGT':'001','JEQ':'010','JGE':'011',
            'JLT':'100','JNE':'101','JLE':'110','JMP':'111'}

    #init SymbolTable
    SymbolTable ={'SP':0,'LCL':1,'ARG':2,'THIS':3,'THAT':4,'SCREEN':16384,'KBD':24576,
                  'R0':0,'R1':1,'R2':2,'R3':3,'R4':4,'R5':5,'R6':6,'R7':7,
                  'R8':8,'R9':9,'R10':10,'R11':11,'R12':12,'R13':13,'R14':14,'R15':15}

    #first pass
    instr_count = 0
    with open(args[0]) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            line = l.strip() #strip space
            line = line.split('//')[0].strip() #strip comment
            if not line:
                continue
            if line[0]=='(':
                symbol = line[1:].split(')')[0] 
                SymbolTable[symbol] = instr_count #ignoring double symbol error
                continue
            #ignoring invalid A_COMMAND & C_COMMAND
            instr_count += 1

    #second pass
    instr_count = 0
    symbol_counter = 16
    with open(args[0]) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            line = l.strip() #strip space
            line = line.split('//')[0].strip() #strip comment
            if not line:
                continue
            if line[0]=='(':
                continue
            #--------------A-COMMAND------------------
            if line[0]=='@': 
                token = line[1:]
                if not token.lstrip('-').isdigit(): 
                    if token not in SymbolTable:
                       SymbolTable[token] = symbol_counter
                       symbol_counter +=1
                    token = SymbolTable[token]
                    #print "0{0:015b}".format(token) #ignoring unknown symbol
                    fw.write("0{0:015b}\n".format(token))
                else:
                    #--- TODO: dealing with negative number
                    if token[0] == '-':
                        #print '0'+tobin(int(token),15)
                        fw.write('0'+tobin(int(token),15)+'\n')
                    else:
                        #print "0{0:015b}".format(int(token)) #ignoring unknown symbol
                        fw.write("0{0:015b}\n".format(int(token)))                        
                instr_count += 1
                continue
            #--------------C-COMMAND------------------
            comp = dest = jump = ""
            if '=' in line:
                token = line.split('=')
                dest = destT[token[0]]
                line = token[1]
            else:
                dest = destT['null']
            token = line.split(';')
            comp = compT[token[0]]
            if ';' in line:
                jump = jumpT[token[1]]
            else:
                jump = jumpT['null']
            #print '111'+comp+dest+jump
            fw.write('111'+comp+dest+jump+'\n')
            instr_count += 1
    fw.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Working with file handles

The program opens a filehandle for writing early on:

> ```
> fw = open(args[0].split('.')[0]+".hack",'w')
> ```

But then it's not used until much further down.

It would be better to open filehandles right before you really need them,
and use the `with open(...) as` syntax,
instead of managing it manually,
to protect yourself from accidentally forgetting to close.

#### Decompose to smaller functions

The `main` functions does too much.
It would be better to split it up to multiple smaller functions with descriptive names.
It would be ideal to decompose to smaller functions with descriptive names that comments would become unnecessary.

The constant dictionaries you define at the beginning of the function make the implementation look a bit noisy.
It might be better to move these near the top of the file.

#### Naming

The variables are quite poorly named.
It's quite hard to follow the code this way.
Try to come up with better, more descriptive names.

Avoid single-letter variable names,
especially names like `l`,
that may look like `1` with some fonts,
and can be especially confusing when used near another variable named `i`.

#### Command line parsing

Instead of `import sys` and parsing command line flags yourself,
I suggest to take a look at [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).
It's really easy to use, and it's awesome.

#### Coding style

- The posted code has violates [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on many counts. I suggest to review the guidelines and apply carefully
- The indentation is odd at a few places. For example the `return` statement in `tobin`
- `snake_case` is recommended for variable and function names. For example, `symbol_table` would be better than `SymbolTable`. Also `to_bin` better than `tobin`. Just to name a few.
- A more idiomatic way of writing `line[0]=='('` is `line.startswith('(')`

#### Prefer Python 3

Judging by the `print` statement without parentheses,
it seems you're on Python 2.
Consider switching to Python 3.

Comment: I posted the revised code as new answer, @janos

Comment: Let me know if you have other comments/inputs specially about performance improvement!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my revised code. It passed [PEP8 online check](http://pep8online.com/). I changed it into python3. I fixed the file handles, parsed the filename using `argparse`, used better naming schemes, and changed into more pythonic/idiomatic way of writing. Basically, it just following all the inputs from @janos.

```
import argparse


# init compTable
compTable = {
    '0': '0101010', '1': '0111111', '-1': '0111010', 'D': '0001100',
    'A': '0110000', '!D': '0001101', '!A': '0110001', '-D': '0001111',
    '-A': '0110011', 'D+1': '0011111', 'A+1': '0110111', 'D-1': '0001110',
    'D+A': '0000010', 'D-A': '0010011', 'A-D': '0000111', 'D&A': '0000000',
    'D|A': '0010101', 'M': '1110000', '!M': '1110001', '-M': '1110011',
    'M+1': '1110111', 'M-1': '1110010', 'D+M': '1000010', 'D-M': '1010011',
    'M-D': '1000111', 'D&M': '1000000', 'D|M': '1010101', 'A-1': '0110010'
    }
# init destTable
destination_table = {'null': '000', 'M': '001', 'D': '010', 'MD': '011',
                     'A': '100', 'AM': '101', 'AD': '110', 'AMD': '111'}

# init jumpTable
jumptTable = {'null': '000', 'JGT': '001', 'JEQ': '010', 'JGE': '011',
              'JLT': '100', 'JNE': '101', 'JLE': '110', 'JMP': '111'}


def tobin(val, nbits):
    return bin((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits))[2:]


def build_symbol_table(filename):
    # init symbol_table
    symbol_table = {
        'SP': 0, 'LCL': 1, 'ARG': 2, 'THIS': 3, 'THAT': 4, 'SCREEN': 16384,
        'KBD': 24576, 'R0': 0, 'R1': 1, 'R2': 2, 'R3': 3, 'R4': 4, 'R5': 5,
        'R6': 6, 'R7': 7, 'R8': 8, 'R9': 9, 'R10': 10, 'R11': 11, 'R12': 12,
        'R13': 13, 'R14': 14, 'R15': 15
    }

    instr_count = 0
    with open(filename) as in_textfile:
        for line in in_textfile:
            line = line.strip()  # strip space
            line = line.split('//')[0].strip()  # strip comment
            if not line:
                continue
            if line.startswith('('):
                symbol = line[1:].split(')')[0]
                symbol_table[symbol] = instr_count
                # ignoring double symbol error
                continue
            # ignoring invalid A_COMMAND & C_COMMAND
            instr_count += 1
    return symbol_table


def main():
    # command-line argument
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='HACK Assembler.')
    parser.add_argument('filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # first pass
    symbol_table = build_symbol_table(args.filename)

    # second pass
    instr_count = 0
    symbol_counter = 16  # after R0-R15
    outname = args.filename.split('.')[0]+".hack"
    with open(args.filename) as in_textfile, open(outname, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in in_textfile:
            line = line.strip()  # strip space
            line = line.split('//')[0].strip()  # strip comment
            if not line:
                continue
            if line.startswith('('):
                continue
            # --------------A-COMMAND------------------
            if line.startswith('@'):
                token = line[1:]
                if not token.lstrip('-').isdigit():
                    if token not in symbol_table:
                        symbol_table[token] = symbol_counter
                        symbol_counter += 1
                    token = symbol_table[token]
                    # print("0{0:015b}".format(token))
                    outfile.write("0{0:015b}\n".format(token))
                else:
                    # dealing with negative number
                    if token[0] == '-':
                        # print('0'+tobin(int(token),15))
                        outfile.write('0'+tobin(int(token), 15)+'\n')
                    else:
                        outfile.write("0{0:015b}\n".format(int(token)))
                instr_count += 1
                continue
            # --------------C-COMMAND------------------
            comp = dest = jump = ""
            if '=' in line:
                token = line.split('=')
                dest = destination_table[token[0]]
                line = token[1]
            else:
                dest = destination_table['null']
            token = line.split(';')
            comp = compTable[token[0]]
            if ';' in line:
                jump = jumptTable[token[1]]
            else:
                jump = jumptTable['null']
            # print('111'+comp+dest+jump)
            outfile.write('111'+comp+dest+jump+'\n')
            instr_count += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```